# How to build a C++ app on Windows with VS Code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, build

I am familiar with POSIX environment, but not Windows. I `git clone` a C++ project then PowerShell into it, then `code .`. When I hit `<F5>`, I don't see any C++ Compiler:

[image]

However, I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio with C++ (20 GB !!). I am able to build the project with Visual Studio, but `Alt-Tab` + `<C-B>` + `Alt-Tab` isn't very nice. What I would like to do is build my project directly in VS Code.

Is there any magical trick?

Comment: Why don't use Visual Studio 2022 Comminity?

Comment: or you could just make a C# application 

Comment: @273K, I really don't like the editor. VS Code is way more user-friendly.

Comment: ***Is there any magical trick?*** You probaby want to use CMake and the CMakeTools extension. But yes Visual Studio community will be a much better user experience.

Comment: Well you could install the necessary extensions in VS Code -or- you could configure the hot keys in VS to work like you want -or- you could use punch cards.

Comment: I tried with CMake, but I spend about one hour trying to gather the libraries and feed CMake. It seems so much easier to do `apt install lib-whatever-dev` than downloading a zip file inflate it somewhere and playing around with the CMake GUI to find what is missing.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Punch cards seem a really good solution, where can I get good punchers?

Comment: ***I tried with CMake, but I spend about one hour trying to gather the libraries and feed CMake.*** There is vcpkg and if you are using MinGW instead of msvc I highly recommend msys2 and using pacman to install your libraries in the mingw64 terminal.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried vcpkg, but I get the error: `error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance ...  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary/Build\vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: @nowox I get all my punch cards off ebay! Wide variety, excellent quality, pretty inexpensive too!

Comment: No magic, just some configuration to do. VSCode calls such things "tasks", so configuration is done in tasks.json. See [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: There is a magic trick, don't start VSCode from regular power shell, instead start the visual studio developer power shell and start VSCode from there. It has the correct environment already set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was cumbersome, but I managed to do something... At least I can build the project with VSCode...

1. Install more stuff from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022. I don't exactly know what is needed. The only thing I know is that something was missing.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22000",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.6.0",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.7.0",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.UniversalBuildTools"
  ]
}
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.TSServer",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Component.CPython39.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22000",
    "Component.OpenJDK",
    "Component.Android.SDK.MAUI",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CLI.Support",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Llvm.Clang",
    "Component.IncredibuildMenu",
    "Component.Incredibuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Component.HAXM.Private",
    "Component.Android.NDK.R23C",
    "Component.Android.Emulator.MDD",
    "Component.MDD.Android",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile",
    "Component.Unreal.Ide",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame",
    "Component.MDD.Linux",
    "Component.Linux.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Embedded",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.34.17.4.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.34.17.4.x86.x64.Spectre"
  ]
}
```

I had to install twice Visual Studio :

- Visual Studio Build Tools 2022
- Visual Studio Community 2022

[image]

2. `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git` under `C:\src\vcpkg`
3. Add `vcpkg` path to system PATH.
4. Reboot the computer (PATH wasn't modified even though I restarted windows terminal)
5. Launch `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022`
6. Navigate to the project
7. Type `code .`
8. Add into `.vscode\settings.json`:

   {
   "cmake.configureSettings": {
   "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "C:/src/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
   }
   }
9. Install the libraries with `vcpkg install ...`
10. Deploy the libraries with `vcpkg integrate install`
11. Install VS Code CMake extension
12. `<C-S-P>CMake: Build`
13. ...
14. PROFIT !

Comment: *"I had to install twice Visual Studio"* - No you don't, the Build Tools is enough. But you do have to follow the VS Code installation guide to the letter. All 15 pages of it.